# How to deal with HTTP error 503 when scraping, even after incorporating Sys.sleep()?

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I am trying to scrape speeches from the Congressional Record. I have written the following code to do so:

```
# install the following packages
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# write a function to extract text of speeches
get_text = function(speech_link) {
  speech_page = read_html(speech_link)
  speech_text = speech_page %>% html_nodes(".styled") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(speech_text)
}

# create empty df 
speeches = data.frame()

# for loop to extract speech heading, date, and text
for(page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 25, by = 1)) {
  link = paste0(
    "https://www.congress.gov/search?pageSort=issueAsc&q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22congrecord%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22covid%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22House%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%22117%22%2C%22116%22%5D%7D&pageSize=100&page=",
    page_result ,
    ""
  )
  
  page = read_html(link)
  
  heading = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading a") %>% html_text()
  speech_links = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")
  date = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading+ .result-item span") %>% html_text()
  text = sapply(speech_links, FUN = get_text)
  Sys.sleep(5)
  
  speeches = rbind(speeches,
                   data.frame(heading, date, text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
  
  
}
```

This works until I reach about the tenth page, at which point I receive the following error. Now I can't even scrape one page. I'm assuming I've overwhelmed the website.

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.
```

After reading previous posts on here, I incorporated `Sys.sleep()` into my loop, as you can see above, but this doesn't make a difference. What am I doing wrong here? Any feedback would be appreciated.

**EDIT: Here is what I did based on the comment below, which still does not work.**

```
# write a function to extract text of speeches
get_text = function(speech_link) {
  speech_page = read_html(speech_link)
  Sys.sleep(1)
  speech_text = speech_page %>% html_nodes(".styled") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(speech_text)
}

# create empty df 
speeches = data.frame()

# for loop to extract speech heading, date, and text
for(page_result in seq(from = 11, to = 25, by = 1)) {
  link = paste0(
    "https://www.congress.gov/search?pageSort=issueAsc&q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22congrecord%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22covid%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22House%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%22117%22%2C%22116%22%5D%7D&pageSize=100&page=",
    page_result ,
    ""
  )
  Sys.sleep(1)
  page = tryCatch(read_html(link), error = function(e){NA})
  
  
  heading = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading a") %>% html_text()
  speech_links = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")
  date = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading+ .result-item span") %>% html_text()
  text = sapply(speech_links, FUN = get_text)
  speeches = rbind(speeches,
                   data.frame(heading, date, text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
  
  
}
```

In fact, I am now getting this new error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.
In addition: Warning message:
In .Internal(get(x, envir, mode, inherits)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2020/12/31/house-section/article/h9169-2?q=%7B%22search%22%3A%5B%22covid%22%2C%22covid%22%5D%7D&s=1&r=1071)
```

Comment: You are out reading the website twice.  Once in the for loop and another time in the sapply function call.  Try adding a 1 sec pause after `speech_page = read_html(speech_link)`.  This may help.  Also, it maybe an issue with a particular link so you may need to enclose `read_html(link)` in a try and catch statement an skip any problems.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. I tried what you suggested (see edits above), but that still doesn't work. In fact, I am now getting an additional error (see above).

Comment: does it help to `closeAllConnections()` after the `read_html()` calls?

Comment: The above message is a warning so that is not a problem, restarting the session should close any open connections.  I was able to process all 25 links from the outer loop without issue so I don't know where you are receiving the error.  You may want to use the try and catch in the get_text function and print out any offending links with errors.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error, but what I think might help you, is to save the source html instead of straight up processing it. This has two major advantages over your approach:

1. You can actually look at the source html and see whether it downloaded properly and if not, see what is wrong in detail.
2. You do not have to ask the server 10 times for the same data, putting more and more strain on it, because you already have some of the data and you can continue where you left off yesterday or a few hours ago, by skipping html that you already saved.

```r
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
getwd()

## empty potential rests from other scripts 
rm(list = ls())

# create a directory for the index pages
if(!dir.exists('index')) dir.create('index')
folder <- 'index'

# create vector with all links
links <- str_c("https://www.congress.gov/search?pageSort=issueAsc&q=%7B%22source%22%3A%22congrecord%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22covid%22%2C%22chamber%22%3A%22House%22%2C%22congress%22%3A%5B%22117%22%2C%22116%22%5D%7D&pageSize=100&page=",1:25)


# loop over it and save pages
i <- 1
for(link in links){
  if(!file.exists(file.path(folder,str_c('page_',i,".html")))){
    httr::GET(link, httr::write_disk(file.path(folder,str_c('page_',i,".html"))))
    i = i + 1
  }
}

# get the source file name
index_files <- list.files(folder, full.names = T)

# process and parse them
speeches <- tibble()
for (file in index_files) {
  page <- rvest::read_html(file)
  heading = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading a") %>% html_text()
  speech_links = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.congress.gov", ., sep = "")
  date = page %>% html_nodes(".congressional-record-heading+ .result-item span") %>% html_text()
  speeches = bind_rows(speeches,
                       data.frame(heading, date, speech_links, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
}

# etc. 
if(!dir.exists('text')) dir.create('text')
folder <- 'text'

speeches <- speeches %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())

for(i in 1:nrow(speeches)){
  if(!file.exists(file.path(folder, str_c('text_',speeches$id[i],".html")))){
    GET(speeches$speech_links[i], 
        write_disk(file.path(folder, str_c('text_',speeches$id[i],".html"))))
  }
}


text_files <- list.files(folder, full.names = T)

# now parse all the text files in a similar fashion...
```